# ionic unable to create an APK

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3

trying to make an apk for debugging a simple app, i use:

```
ionic cordova platform add android
```

and

```
ionic cordova build android
```

the result is, i get platform/android with bunch of files inside, but no apk!

the error i get on the cli says:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:8236) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code
```

i have installed android studio, and java jdk, i also added android as a system variable, although i must say, i am quite a noob, so i only followed instruction and could've made mistakes i guess.
question is, what to do now?

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, any new code you've tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers aren't working, will bump it to the top of the active queue.

Comment: have you tried by removing node_modules folder, removing android platform and then reinstall all, using npm install, and  ionic cordova add android

Comment: @MikeM. This error is not related to the link that you have mentioned, It is related with installed platform and ionic dependencies

Comment: What are you talking about? This is a blatant repeat, with identical commands, identical  – though pared down – error logs, and identical result and problem description.